# Comparison of 2 dataframes based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in df1 and df2. Based on `Interval` column value in df1, I want to take out specific `Start` and `End` from df2 which matches the interval value in df1.

```
df1:
ID     Interval
1      annual
2      quarterly
3      semiannual
```

```
df2:
ID  Start       End
1   AUG-FY21    JAN-FY22
1   AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
1   AUG-FY21    JUL-FY22
2   AUG-FY21    JAN-FY22
2   AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
3   AUG-FY21    JAN-FY22
3   AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
3   AUG-FY21    JUL-FY22
```

```
output:
ID  Interval    Start       End
1   annual      AUG-FY21    JUL-FY22
2   quarterly   AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
3   semiannual  AUG-FY21    JAN-FY22
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to just take the start date and add the required months to it in order to create the end date, as opposed to trying to find the actual row from df2?

Comment: Nope. Im getting the df2 from database and I have to take other rows too based on this criteria. So I can take only the values

Comment: Can you show how you've begun and where it's going wrong?  What should happen if there's no value that matches your criteria?  What if there's more than one value for an interval?

Comment: 1: For ID==3 , Startdate is lower than end date in the example (df2) , 2: For Id 1 , Aug21 to Aug22 is 1 year (this means count starts from September , next month) , whereas for Id 2  , Aug-Oct (not November is considered a quarted , count starts from same month), Can you please check and explain?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using pandas to merge both dataframes after computing the difference in days and arbitrarily define labels to intervals.

```
# reproduce the test case
import pandas as pd
data_1 = {'ID': [1, 2, 3],
          'Interval': ['annual', 'quarterly', 'semiannual']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
data_2 = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
          'Start': ['AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21', 'AUG-FY21'],
          'End': ['JAN-FY21', 'OCT-FY21', 'AUG-FY22', 'JAN-FY21', 'OCT-FY21', 'JAN-FY21', 'OCT-FY21', 'AUG-FY22']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

# compute the days interval based on start and stop
df2['Days_interval'] = (pd.to_datetime(df2.End.str.replace('-FY', ' 20')) - pd.to_datetime(df2.Start.str.replace('-FY', ' 20'))).abs().dt.days
df2['Interval'] = ''

# assign labels based on days interval
df2.loc[df2['Days_interval'] < 100, 'Interval'] = 'quarterly'
df2.loc[(df2['Days_interval'] >= 100) & (df2['Days_interval'] <= 300), 'Interval'] = 'semiannual'
df2.loc[df2['Days_interval'] > 300, 'Interval'] = 'annual'

# exclude helper columns
df2.drop('Days_interval', axis = 1, inplace = True)

# merge both dfs by ID and interval
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on = ['ID', 'Interval'])
# exclude helper columns from original df
df2.drop('Interval', axis = 1, inplace = True)

output
    ID  Interval    Start       End
0   1   annual      AUG-FY21    AUG-FY22
1   2   quarterly   AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
2   3   semiannual  AUG-FY21    JAN-FY21
```

Comment: What if the FY starts from Feb?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, once what matters is the days in between dates, and the arbitrary interpretation of what constitutes annual, semiannual and quaterly.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Start` and `End` columns to dates, get the number of months between them, then use a dictionary to replace the timedelta with the words you want.  Merge and convert your datetimes back to strings.

```
import pandas as pd

offsets= {11:'annual',
         2:'quarterly',
         5:'semiannual'}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Interval': ['annual', 'quarterly', 'semiannual']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 'Start': ['AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21','AUG-FY21'],
 'End': ['JAN-FY22','OCT-FY21','JUL-FY22','JAN-FY22','OCT-FY21','JAN-FY22','OCT-FY21','JUL-FY22']})


df2['Start'] =pd.to_datetime(df2['Start'], format='%b-FY%y')
df2['End'] =pd.to_datetime(df2['End'], format='%b-FY%y')
df2['Interval'] = df2.apply(lambda x: len(pd.date_range(start=x['Start'], end=x['End'], freq='M')), axis=1)

df2['Interval'] = df2['Interval'].replace(offsets)

output = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','Interval'], how='left')

output['Start'] = output['Start'].dt.strftime(date_format='%b-FY%y').str.upper()
output['End'] = output['End'].dt.strftime(date_format='%b-FY%y').str.upper()
```

Output

```
    ID    Interval     Start         End
0    1      annual  AUG-FY21    JUL-FY22
1    2   quarterly  AUG-FY21    OCT-FY21
2    3  semiannual  AUG-FY21    JAN-FY22
```